# Move/copy and rename most recently modified file

Tags: php, rename

I have a folder with some randomly named files that contain data that I need.

In order to use the data, I have to move the files to another folder and name the file 'file1.xml'

Every time a file is moved and renamed, it replaces a previous 'file1.xml' in the destination folder.

The source folder contains all the other randomly named files which are kept as an archive.

The php will be run via a cron job every 48 hours

The following works, but it's for ftp. I need to edit it for local files.

```
$conn = ftp_connect('ftp.source.com'); ftp_login($conn, 'username', 'password'); // get file list $files = ftp_nlist($conn, '/data'); $mostRecent = array( 'time' => 0, 'file' => null ); foreach ($files as $file) { // get the last modified time $time = ftp_mdtm($conn, $file); if ($time > $mostRecent['time']) { // this file is the most recent so far $mostRecent['time'] = $time; $mostRecent['file'] = $file; } } ftp_get($conn, "/destinationfolder/file1.xml", $mostRecent['file'], FTP_BINARY); ftp_close($conn);
```

Comment: So do you want to create a php script as a cronjob that copies the latest file from one folder to another every 48 hours and overwrites the file there? What have you tried so far?

Comment: $conn = ftp_connect('ftp.source.com');
ftp_login($conn, 'username', 'password');

// get file list
$files = ftp_nlist($conn, '/data');

$mostRecent = array(
    'time' => 0,
    'file' => null
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    // get the last modified time
    $time = ftp_mdtm($conn, $file);

    if ($time > $mostRecent['time']) {
        // this file is the most recent so far
        $mostRecent['time'] = $time;
        $mostRecent['file'] = $file;
    }
}

ftp_get($conn, "/destinationfolder/file1.xml", $mostRecent['file'], FTP_BINARY);

ftp_close($conn);

Comment: The above works. But it's for ftp. I'm a bit of a noob, I'm trying to convert that so that it works for local files rather than remote.
I'm running on cpanel, so I once I have a php script I run it through the cpanel cron jobs

Comment: Well could you please update/edit your question instead adding code in comment?

Comment: Sorry, it's one of the first questions I've posted here. Not sure how it all works

Comment: Take your time. You are close you just need to add some line breaks. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it but I think this should work (comparing your ftp script):

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect('ftp.source.com');
ftp_login($conn, 'username', 'password'); 
    // get file list 
$files = ftp_nlist($conn, '/data'); 
$mostRecent = array( 'time' => 0, 'file' => null ); 
foreach ($files as $file) { 
        // get the last modified time 
    $time = ftp_mdtm($conn, $file); 
    if ($time > $mostRecent['time']) { 
        // this file is the most recent so far 
        $mostRecent['time'] = $time; 
        $mostRecent['file'] = $file; 
    } 
} 
ftp_get($conn, "/destinationfolder/file1.xml", $mostRecent['file'], FTP_BINARY); ftp_close($conn); 
?>
```

**New**:

```
<?php
$sourceDir = "./data";
$destDir = "./destinationfolder";
if (!is_dir($sourceDir) || !is_dir($destDir)) {
    exit("Directory doesn't exists.");
}
if (!is_writable($destDir)) {
    exit("Destination directory isn't writable.");
}
$mostRecentFilePath = "";
$mostRecentFileMTime = 0;
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($sourceDir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getMTime() > $mostRecentFileMTime) {
            $mostRecentFileMTime = $fileinfo->getMTime();
            $mostRecentFilePath = $fileinfo->getPathname();
        }
    }
}
if ($mostRecentFilePath != "") {
    if (!rename($mostRecentFilePath, $destDir . "/file1.xml")) {
        exit("Unable to move file.");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That worked a perfectly thank you. I did change !rename to !copy so I could keep the original. But other than that it worked exactly as I needed it too. Thanks a whole heap for your help.

Comment: Don't add a comment with thanks vote up my solution instead please. Thanks in advance.  and ✔ if you don't need more help with your question.

Comment: I don't have a good enough reputation for my votes to be visible yet